# Trigger email with the link to approve or Reject the Jenkins Job in a pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Pipeline script written where it triggers a Job A and waits for the confirmation from user to proceed with the next job B. I have an email notification written below which sends email to check the console output in Jenkins and approve or reject

My requirement is would it be possible to send two links in the email one to approve and the other to reject? Would it need a dynamic session ID or Job ID parameter posted in the URL

Script :

```
mail (to: 'XXXXXXX@.com',
     subject: "Job '${env.JOB_BASE_NAME}' (${env.BUILD_NUMBER}) is waiting for input",
     body: "Please go to console output of ${env.BUILD_URL} to approve or Reject.");
def userInput = input(id: 'userInput', message: 'Job A Failed do you want to build Job B?', ok: 'Yes')
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is not easy. A away could be that the email is in HTML format and it contains a form which has wanted buttons, but before it sends POST query it injects some Javascript to get crumb from Jenkins API. However, such Javascript is usually blocked by email readers.

Comment: I would suggest to email link to `env.BUILD_URL + 'input'` to get a nice dialogue with the question. (`http://server:port/jenkins/job/foo/15/input`)

Comment: @Lav : Did you achieve the use case ?